# Unequal variances (linear mixed modeling in R)

Tags: mixed-model, variance, linear

I have a dataset as follows:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(multcomp)

treatment = c(rep("AB",14), rep("aB",15), rep("Ab",15), rep("ab",15))
experiment = sample(c(29,30), length(treatment), replace = TRUE)
rate = c(runif(29, min=0, max=0.2), runif(30, min=0, max=1))
d = data.frame(treatment = treatment, experiment = experiment, rate = rate)
```

There are basically four treatment groups (one has 14 samples, the others have 15 samples). Each sample was collected on one of two experiment dates (29 or 30). Each sample also recorded a "rate" (response variable of interest) between the values of 0 and 1.

I am interested to see which pairs of treatment groups show significant differences. After plotting the data, I could see that there was pretty large unequal variances. In the MWE data, this looks as follows:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=treatment, y=rate)) + geom_boxplot(fill="palegreen2")
```

[image]

For now, I ran a linear mixed model and Tukey post-hoc comparison the data, as follows:

```
mortcomp2 = lme(rate ~ treatment, data=d, random = ~1|experiment) 
summary(glht(mortcomp2, linfct=mcp(treatment="Tukey")))
```

I wanted to inquire for opinions on whether there are other models to apply for this situation? Particularly, are there alternative models that would better take into account the unequal variance in my data?

Any ideas greatly welcomed!

Comment: Two things draw my intention: the box plot does not show the variances, afaik it just displays the data "Tukey style". And could you remind me what MWE stands for?

Comment: Thanks @cherub. I was not as concerned about showing the variances. I was more concerned about if there are unequal variances, what model could be used instead to account for this more rigorously (if the model I used is not appropriate for cases of unequal variances). Sorry for the acronym. By MWE, I meant "Minimal working example". It means it is not my real data, but is a self-contained and simple reproducible example of my data and issue.